# Link type in Plone 4.0.2 stopped working

Tags: plone

I'm working on a Plone 4.0.2 website that for awhile has been running smoothly, but just recently the Link contenttype has stopped functioning as it should. Regardless of being logged in or not all that is ever seen is the page saying "The link address is :[target URL]". Also when creating/editing a link the info message that usually says "you're seeing this because you have permission to edit..." isn't showing up. I've attempted to reinstall archetypes and no change occ

Comment: What was the version of Plone that it last worked under?  What add-ons do you have installed?  Are you sure you're not logged in?  Try it in a totally separate browser that you've never logged in with.

Comment: I've done as you've suggested already to make sure I wasn't logged in and it is just as i have said. It last worked under Plone 4.0.2 and in a stock install of Plone 4.0.2 it does in fact run. As for add-ons, quintagroup.seoptimizer, webcouturier.dropdownmenu, z3c.jbot, and collective.redirect. Collective.redirect is also based on the link contenttype so it also has stopped working.

Comment: What happens when you  remove collective.redirect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in portal_skins/plone_content there is a view called link_redirect_view a Script (Python)
that normally does the job :
here is the doc :

```
Redirect to the Link target URL, if and only if:
  - redirect_links property is enabled in portal_properties/site_properties
 - AND current user doesn't have permission to edit the Link
```

I would check with  /select_default_view what is the default view of the link.
If there is no link_redirect_view available I would go and see what is going on in portal_types as  Jihaisse said. Could it be that quintagroup.seoptimizer has something to do with the problem ? It happened to me and I've got quintagroup.seoptimizer, hmm..

Actually, since it happened to me again (may because uninstall quintagroup.seoptimizer)  To have my redirections in the same way as before I had to go /@@types-controlpanel and ask to see the type Link : there it was a setting call some things like .. "direct redirection"

Comment: the doc you posted help me greatly. I was unaware of there bing a redirect_links property and some how it got disabled. Thanks a lot for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the default view of the link.
It's like it's base_view not link_view.
You can see this directly on the link by choosing the view action, or in the ZMI in portal_types.

If the view has changed, it's surely because of an add-on.