# Plone link type - open external site

Tags: plone

I have added a link to my left nav menu, which points to an external link. When I click the link it displays a view saying "The link address is: http://externalsite.com"

How do I get the link to open directly, rather than displaying this message/view?

My version info is:

- Plone 2.5.4-2
- Zope (Zope 2.9.8-final, python 2.4.3, linux2)

I have tried editing the link type in portal_types in the ZMI, but there is no option there to "Redirect immediately to link target" as suggested by this answer - [How can I add a menu entry that links to an external site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917848/how-can-i-add-a-menu-entry-that-links-to-an-external-site)

Comment: According to this it also depends on whether your user has permission to edit the link, and what the redirect_links property is set to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111661/link-type-in-plone-4-0-2-stopped-working

Comment: If you want that also the user who create the link will be redirect to the link destination, change the ownership of the link item using the http://yoursite/linkpath/ownership_form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here - http://plone.org/documentation/kb/repurpose-link-object
It turns out the link is behaving as expected, but displays that view to the author so that the link can be edited. It redirects for users.

> *If you create a link, people will get sent directly to its target when
>   clicked. If you are the Owner of the item, you will be sent to the
>   view page so you can edit it, though.*

Answer (score 0):

Bounce from a page template using meta refresh redirect?